# Printing two Google Maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, printing

I have a simple page with two google maps.  They are in two DIV elements.  there is a page-break-after:always on the first DIV.  It looks fine on the screen BUT does not print correctly.  The second google map has a strange distortion.  It is as if the second row of map tiles on the second map has forgotten where it belongs.
It actually prints fine in IE 11 but not in IE 9 or chrome.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>Google Maps API v3 - Two maps</title>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    function initialize()
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.520266,73.856406);
        var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.579943,77.330006);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var myOptions2 =
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng2,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);

        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Pune"
       });

        var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: latlng2,
            map: map2,
            title:"Noida"
        });
    }
    //]]>  

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="top: 10px; left: 25px; width:800px; height:600px;page-break-after:always"></div>
<div id="map_canvas_2" style="top: 10px; left: 25px; width:800px; height:600px"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I made a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tr5qu9py/), and it seems work fine. Can you please check it?

Comment: I don't think JS fiddle will do the trick - it is printing related.   The problem is that it looks fine on the screen but it does not print properly from Google Chrome or IE9.  At first it looks fine, but if you look closely you will notice that the second map is distorted.